# Executing logstash command outside of docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to execute a Logstash command to start importing to Elasticsearch without entering the ELK Docker container.

**This doesn't work:**

`docker exec -it docker_elk_1 opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/configs/logstash-logs.config`

Although it would show 
`Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}` but it would just exit after.

However, this would work, but I have to enter docker container first

`docker exec -it docker_elk_1 bin/bash`

Then

`opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/configs/logstash-logs.config`

Thanks

**docker-compose.yml**

```
elk:
  image: sebp/elk
  volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/home/configs
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    - "9200:9200"
    - "5044:5044"
```

Comment: How you are running the docker ELK container?

Comment: docker-compose up -d --build

Comment: Can you give the details of the docker-compose yml file? and Dockerfiles.

Comment: There's no Dockerfiles. Just docker-compose.yml. Updated my post

Comment: I see that you are working with sebp/elkx example correct?

Comment: I'm not working on their example, I'm trying to import my logs out the docker container instead of doing it via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand...you can try with:

```
docker exec -it docker_elk_1 /bin/bash -c 'opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/configs/logstash-logs.config'
```

or

```
docker-compose exec /bin/bash -c 'opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/configs/logstash-logs.config'
```